# existence of spanning trees in complete graphs implies choice?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, axiom-of-choice

it is known that the existence of spanning trees in arbitrary (connected) graphs implies the Axiom of Choice. I was wondering if this result still holds if we restrict ourselves to spanning trees of complete graphs. Does the Axiom of Choice still follow?

I would be very happy if you can provide a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't think so.
A complete graph should always have a spanning tree.

Pick your favorite vertex $u$ from the vertex set $V$, infinite or not, and construct a giant star tree
with $u$ as the center.
That is, construct the tree $T = (V, F)$ where the edge set is $F = \{uv : v \in V \setminus \{u\} \}$.  This has to be a spanning tree
(and as pointed out in comments,note that you don't need the axiom of choice to pick an element from a single set $V$).

So denote by $S$ the statement "every complete graph has a spanning tree".
If the statement "$S$ implies the axiom of choice" is true, then the axiom of choice is true since $S$ is true.  So this implication cannot be - or otherwise you'd have a proof of the axiom of choice.

Comment: But didn't you use the axiom of choice in order to pick a vertex $u$?

Comment: @Viniciusdos: You don't need to use the axiom of choice for picking one element from a non-empty set.

Comment: While the proof itself is fine, I do have a minor issue with its phrasing. Not everything which is not provable without the axiom of choice implies the axiom of choice. And it is common to say that something requires the axiom of choice, even when it only needs less (e.g. "You need the axiom of choice to well-order the real numbers", even if a well-ordering of the real numbers is much much much weaker than the axiom of choice itself).

Comment: I did try to rephrase because that's not what was meant (assuming I understand your point correctly).  The point is that $S$ is provable without the axiom of choice.  And if $S$ implies the axiom of choice, then you can prove the axiom of choice without it being an axiom.  So $S$ cannot imply the axiom of choice.